# Select records from another table between result set dates

Tags: oracle

I have a **result set** like this (I have to execute a query to get it from a contract table):

```
OBJECT_ID     START_DT     END_DT

1             01/01/2011   12/31/2011
2             08/08/2008   09/30/2013
3             10/01/2008   10/31/2013
..
..
```

That specifies the dates that some objects were active on a contract.

I also have another table (call it `OBJ_EVENTS`) like this:

```
OBJECT_ID     EVENT_DATE     EVENT_TYPE

1             10/10/2010     FOO EVENT
1             01/05/2011     BAR EVENT
1             01/01/2012     FOO EVENT
2             08/09/2008     FOO EVENT
4             10/10/2010     BAZ EVENT
```

That table tells me when some object did things I might be interested in. But, I only care about events between the contract dates `START_DT` and `END_DT` for the objects in my contract result set. So, if that was my whole `OBJ_EVENTS` table, my desired result set looks like this:

```
OBJECT_ID     EVENT_DATE     EVENT_TYPE

1             01/05/2011     BAR EVENT --between Obj 1's contract dates 01/01/2011-12/31/2011
2             08/09/2008     FOO EVENT --between Obj 2's contract dates 08/08/2008-09/30/2013
```

Is it possible to accomplish this in one SQL query or do I need to do some kind of cursor? I don't have a ton of sql experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the query you're using to obtain your first result set as a sub-query, something like:

```
select oe.OBJECT_ID, oe.EVENT_DATE, oe.EVENT_TYPE
from OBJ_EVENTS oe inner join
( *result set query here*) rs
on oe.OBJECT_ID = rs.OBJECT_ID and
  oe.EVENT_DATE between rs.START_DT and rs.END_DT;
```

That might not be the *best* way to do it, but it should get the job done. In particular, if your result set doesn't change often, it may be worth caching that query's results in a regular table. Whether it changes often or not, if the result set is referenced often, it could be useful to create a view for it.